# Google Contacts API not showing emails, nor max results

Tags: oauth, google-contacts-api

I'm using the [**Google Contacts API**](http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/) to get back formatted JSON, hopefully containing ***ALL*** of a user's contacts' email addresses. I use this information to search my database for the user's friends.

*Neither of these results occur.*

**Here's the URI that's called** (broken up by paramater for slightly better readability:

`http://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/@me/@all/?`
`filterby=emails&max_results=1000`
`&oauth_consumer_key=XXXXXXX`
`&oauth_nonce=h7ZEI`
`&oauth_signature=6U2ywoPRFu8iJdQhjMRk%2FZlf%2FBg%3D`
`&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1`
`&oauth_timestamp=1283979209`
`&oauth_token=1%2Fwv9OYV4LuffVLv6OqlFJLOtTlBo5sYYQkHbZznlLrNk`
`&oauth_version=1.0`
`&orderby=starttime`

**Here's some truncated and anonymized JSON I have returned.**

```
{
    "startIndex": 0,
    "totalResults": 615,
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "name": {
                "formatted": "XXXXX XXXXXX",
                "familyName": "XXXXXXX",
                "givenName": "XXXXXX"
            },
            "displayName": "XXXXX XXXXXX"
        },
    ],
    "itemsPerPage": 20
}
```

Any thoughts on what's going wrong here would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question so soon, but I was using the wrong initial scope. I was using Google's Open Social feed rather than the Google Contacts feed.